# Геообъекты добавлены на карту через ObjectManager, но при переходе по ссылке на карте "Открыть в Яндекс.картах" геообъектов нет

Tags: яндекс-карты

Геообъекты добавлены на карту через ObjectManager, но при переходе по ссылке на карте "Открыть в Яндекс.картах" геообъектов нет. Не могу понять как передать объекты или где искать информацию

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите возможности запуска веб-версии Яндекс.Карт через параметры URL:
https://yandex.ru/dev/yandex-apps-launch/maps/doc/concepts/yandexmaps-web.html

Они весьма ограничены и поддерживают лишь метки. Фактически у вас есть возможность показать на карте лишь десяток точек из API-карты. Никаких линий, кругов или полигонов карта уже не отобразит.

Сам по себе этот переход нужен в первую очередь для построения маршрута к конкретной точке и именно с таким прицелом он, судя по всему, и был создан. То, что оказалось возможным отобразить не одну, а несколько точек - скорее бонус, а не самоцель.